# WP7 - Best way to store secure data

Tags: c#, security, windows-phone-7, encryption, data-storage

I am curious, what is the best way to store data on Windows Phone 7 in a secure way like a password etc.

I explored the `ProtectedData` option, but is this the best way of storing(encrypting) data? If so what is the best way of implementing this option?

Comment: Please do not use an encryption method to store passwords. You should use a hasing algorithm ( any supported one by WP7.x will do.

Comment: Storing passwords encrypted was a poor example, I intend to use it for credentials. But thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good article about secure storing data by Rob Tiffany!
You can find it [here...](http://robtiffany.com/encrypting-your-credentials-on-windows-phone-7-5/)